# problem on sequelize while using variable

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing error on sequelize while using variable for instance

```
let article = await Article.findAll({
        offset:0,
        limit:5
      });
```

is working perfectly but if i :

```
const {pageNumber,limit} = req.params;
    const offset = ((pageNumber-1) * limit);
    
    let article = await Article.findAll({
        offset,
        limit
      });
```

console logging both offset and limit values shows the value given through routes. But i got this error on my console

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse limit as integer before setting up the value or do it before using it in the sequelize e.g

limit = parseInt(limit,10);

Comment: it worked thanks ... so value in parms are always string??

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it has helped and yeah thats what i have noticed. Even after assigning integer values it turns out to be string in query params.

Comment: satwinder i cant upvote ur answer I dont have much  reputation points to do that

Comment: No worries. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try this? the javascript version may not allow you to do it that way.

```
let article = await Article.findAll({
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit
  });
```

If this does not work, you could publish the error and the sql generated that appears in the console and i could help you more.

**EDIT:**

Try add + before for numerical value limit. limit receives an integer as value: `+req.params.limit` or `parseInt(req.params.limit)`

Comment: i did and it didnt work...how to generate the sql can u tell me?

Comment: In your options of the sequelize add the logging param [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging)

Comment: Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `post`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userId` FROM `articles` AS `article` LIMIT 0, '5';

Comment: something like this `logging: console.log` in the instance the sequelize()

Comment: I am not sure, but try add + before for numerical value +limit . limit receives an integer as value.

Comment: at what part should i add + ?

Comment: `let article = await Article.findAll({
        offset: offset,
        limit: +limit
      });`